# Is it possible to run Android 2.2 app on Android 2.2+ Platforms (Gingerbraid, Ice Cream Sandwich etc.)

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it's possible because I am interested in developing applications for the Android platform, but I'm just starting.

Comment: This doesn't really ask a specific programming question and could have been answered by a quick Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. If what you want to know is:

- If I develop an application targeted to Android 2.2, will it run on newer versions of Android?

Then the answer is: probably. The only scenario that can cause your application stop running on newer versions is if you use some feature that is removed from the Android API.

You can also control in your manifest which is the minimum version (and maximum) of the API that your app will run. In that case, it won't be possible to install your application in a device that has some version of the Android which is not in the interval you determined.

You can read more about that here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here are some [reading materials](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

yes.. it's possible... that's the point... :) but 2.3+ apps on 2.2 no...